# How to copy selected text in an SMS message

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sms, htc-sense, htc-one, copy-paste

what I would like to do is be able to take a text message and copy a PORTION of it to use somewhere else. This comes in handy if an email address or phone number wasn't automatically picked up. Especially if it's part of a long text.

The problem is that I can only copy the entire text message, and the text selection arrows never show up. I have used several sms apps and they all seem to do this.

Usually, I long press on the message, then a screen pops up asking me what I want to do. I select copy, and now all the text is in my clipboard. However, as stated above, I only want a portion of that text, not all of it.

If you are wondering, I have an HTC One, running Android 4.4.2 and HTC Sense 5.5.

If anyone knows a way to do this, please let me know. I'm open to using a different SMS app if that's what it takes. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*This is not a direct solution, but a workaround.*

You could forward the message (but not send it); this is a feature the stock Messaging app supports. When you forward a message, it puts that message into edit mode, as if you were sending a new message. From here, you can select the text that you want to copy.

Comment: After spending some more time searching around the web, this seems to be the way other people have figured out to do this. Does anyone know why they make this so hard?

Answer (score 2):

I copy entire message and paste it as a reply. And from there I copy what I need. Mostly passwords. Then I remove rest of the text so it won't stay as a draft.

Answer (score 1):

With [Textra SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra) you can copy selected text

Answer (score 0):

Since I only need to modify a standard SMS answer, I found that : swipe the model/standard  message to the right then menu copy text works, then open new SMS and paste in it; then delete whatever is not appropriate anymore.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone still having this issue like I did; try double-tapping on a message, on oxygenOS it opens the message in a new view and selecting becomes possible.